# Lock pdf in PDFCreator

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I hope there are someone who have used PDFCreator before.

I am using PDFcreator in .NET to automate our PDFing mechanism.

All seems to be working fine apart from the security options.

Even though, I have set the UsePDFSecurity =  1; and PDFDisallowPrinting= 1; the print button
still available. However, if I use the PDFCreator program when prnting from word and select UseSecurity, and DisallowPrinting, the print button is disabled on the generated pdf. Clearly I am missing something in the code as it is normally working.

Has anyone used this feature before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer I think; In addition to PDFUseSecurity property, the PDFOwnerPass and 
PDFOwnerPasswordString properties should be set too.

PDFUseSecurity = 1;
PDFOwnerPass = 1;
PDFOwnerPasswordString = "Password";

this will provide user to set other security properties successfully such as DisasslowPrinting, DisallowCopyig and so on

I just wanted to port the answer as someone else may need that.

Cheers

Mesut